# DELL XPS Bios update to resolve battery issues

Tags: bios, battery

The battery on my DELL XPS (edit: @ author insert model) does not charge.
A BIOS update should resolve the battery issues, but when I try to run the bios update file downloaded from dell support, it shows:

> The battery must have at least 10% of charge.

I already tried to run it whith /forceit parameter. No success! I also tried to to run it with a Flash Boot driver, but it returns that the file isn´t a DOS file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like your battery is dead.  Have you tried it while having a known-good battery inserted?

Comment: There is a lot of topics saying that maybe it´s an issue in the bios. I just want to be sure that is the battery or not.

Comment: another thing: have you maybe tried deleting the battery in device manager before updating?

Comment: This is a good idea, I didn´t tried this yet. But I will.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's possible to manipulate the .exe update file to run on low battery. If you could tell us the whole model number I will have a look into it, if you can't do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late on my feedback. The model is : XPS M1530, the files I´m trying to use is the last bios update released: Dell XPS M1530 System BIOS, A12, link: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=P0FRC

Comment: The forceit parameter didn´t worked out. I´ve tried this already, with adminisrator privileges. Apparently it ignores the parameter. Another detail is that in Dell site it says that the file should run on dos mode, but it didnt too.

Comment: I just read this command has to be executed in a MS-DOS environment. So DOS-mode on Windows won't change a thing cause it's only _"translating"_ for Windows. You will have to make a bootable MS-DOS disc/usb with the update file on it. Then boot from that stick and execute the update with the `/forceint` parameter. There are pre-build images available, e.g. at [THIS](http://www.chtaube.eu/computers/freedos/bootable-usb/) place.